# Android Studio : Compiling with API level 16

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-studio, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-sdk-tools

I was trying to compile an Android with API level 16. However, I am getting following errors. Is it possible to compile an app with API level 16 using android studio or Eclipse now ?

```
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr android:actionModeShareDrawable'

Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'

Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'

Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.

Error goes like that.. Total 118 errors..
```

Following is what I have installed in my Android Studio:

1. Android SDK Tools 24.0.2
2. Android SDK Platform-Tools 21
3. Android SDK build tools 20
4. Android 4.1.2 (API 16).

I have set Compile with : API level 16 also.

Is there anything else required to compile it with API level 16 ? How can I get rid of these errors? Could someone help me with this ? Thank you so much.

EDIT:

### File build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### build.gradle for app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mtes.sidek.techer"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

### SDK Manager:

[image]

### Compile with settings:

[image]

Comment: Show your gradle file.Also have post the image of your SDK manager

Comment: @goonerdroid, I have added the image of SDK manager and gradle file. Is this okay ? Thank you.

Comment: Change your buildToolsVersion to 21.1.2.Also in your SDK manager have you installed Google Repository,Google Support Repository,Android Support Library,Google Play services,

Comment: @goonerdroid, I have made the changes as you have asked. Still the same errors. I have updated SDK manager and Compile with images accordingly. But I am stuck on the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppCompat v21` builds themes that require the new APIs provided in API 21 (Android 5.0). To compile your application with AppCompat, you must also compile against API 21. The recommended setup for compiling/building with API 21 is a compileSdkVersion of 21 and a buildToolsVersion of 21.0.1 (which is the highest at this time - you always want to use the latest build tools).Also if you want to compile with 16 then compile Appcompat using this `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'`

Comment: Yes, compilation error are gone. Thank you so much. One more doubt, if I need to build app with just API level 16. Do I need to use old buildTools ? Is version of 21.0.1 is enough? I want to test some bugs in the API level 16 build apps. So I need exactly API level 16 ? Does buildToolVersion effect my research ?

Comment: It is just a matter of preference.I myself use only the latest build tools ie v21.1.2,cause downloading all build tools takes up my hard disk space .Would suggest you to download the latest build tools.Also accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: goonerdriod, Thank you!

Comment: No problemo,happy coding!